# can i get my eclipse project path using servlet or jsp code?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

```
 <%=session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %>
        <%
            String path= session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(path+"\\testingfile.txt");

        %>
```

The above code is my jsp code after i run this page it will show the following output.

```
C:\Users\Stark\Documents\Eclipse IDE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Demo\
```

Why i get this path ? instead of i want to get the following path which is i needed ...

```
C:\Users\Stark\Documents\Eclipse IDE\Demo
```

How to solve this ? i need this project location for uploading my files into this location so help me !

Comment: Why would your webapp need that path? It won't have it when the webapp is deployed for production use.

Comment: *FYI:* Don't use snippets for Java code. Snippets are for JavaScript only.

Comment: Yes i dont need that path, but i have to upload file that should be within the project folder right ? then how can i upload these files in using relative path ? But in netbeans its working fine it show the correct absolute path but eclipse show .metadata folder.

Comment: You can't upload into project folder. As I already said, when you deploy the code to a server, **there is no project folder**. You can't even upload next to java files or resource files, because they are all inside jar files or war files. Any file created by the webapp, including uploaded files, must be stored somewhere else, outside the project folder / deployment location.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting "weird" path is simple-You are using Eclipse.
When you run an application on Eclipse, Eclipse side will create new path and run your app there. This is why "getRealPath("/")" is giving you weird path, because your app is now running on a temporary folder.

**Why is Eclipse doing this? Here is What I think**

1. In this way, Eclipse can run your app faster(Cached App or codes etc...)
2. Your Original code will keep in safe with any unnecessary changes made by Eclipse.

**So how can I solve this issue?**

I suggest you use "Properties" class for setting upload path. This way you can divide URL setting from your logic and your code will become easy to be maintained. And you won't encounter any unexpected "environmental" error like this, because your setting value will be fixed by your input.

Here is fixed code for using "Properties".

```
<%

Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    // get the property for upload path
    String path=prop.getProperty("path.upload");
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(path+"\\testingfile.txt");

    //TODO:rest of your logic codes will come here.

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
%>
```

You must create "config.properties" file as well. Here is the contents of the file.

```
path.upload=C:\Users\Stark\Documents\Eclipse IDE\Demo
```

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: your answer is pretty good, but i cant get my uploaded file (for example : i have upload the image file and i just try to view the image by using <img src="path"> but it shows error of 'you cant access the local file ') why its happning ?